# Load WPF Image List async, in specific order

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a list of image paths which I need to update a UI with in an async manner:

```
foreach (string path in paths) {
    Task.Run(x => {
        var bitmap = getBitmap(path);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() => Images.Add(new Image() { Source = bitmap; }));
    }); 
}
```

This works great, except that the order my images are added aren't necessarily the order in which they exist in the list of `paths` (this is expected behavior, or course, though not desired behavior).

Is there a way to run a loop of tasks in such a manner that one task does not complete until the prior task is completed?

I don't really care about the `getBitmap` queue order, but I want the Dispatch to happen in the same order as they're called per the `paths` list.

If I can't control the order of each Dispatch invocation itself, is there a way I can order the tasks themselves so that one doesn't run until the prior one is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already on the UI thread, and you just want to prevent `getBitmap` from running on the UI thread and blocking, the best and simplest way would be to use `async`/`await` which will save you the need to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` too.

You code would look like this:

```
foreach (string path in paths) {        
    var bitmap = await Task.Run(() => getBitmap(path));
    Images.Add(new Image { Source = bitmap });
}
```

Alternatively if this is not an option, you could use PLINQs `.AsParallel().AsOrdered()` like so:

```
var bitmaps =
  paths.AsParallel()
       .AsOrdered()
       .Select(getBitmap)

foreach (var bitmap in bitmaps)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() => Images.Add(new Image { Source = bitmap }));
}
```

But remember that you lose some of the benefits of parallelism when retaining order.